# Date range Search using sql and vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Hi im having a problem with date range search in SQL using vb.net.....im using a date picker. the database consist of 2012 -2013 data.

Every time i search date for ex. 10/01/2013 to 10/15/2013 the 2012 data also shows....anyone can help? please

I've created this view

```
SELECT EMPNO, EMPNAME,
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),DTDATE,103) AS LogDate, 
        CONVERT(CHAR(10),DTDATE,108) AS LogTime
From LogTransactions
```

and the VB.NET script is:

```
strSQLSelect = " SELECT " _ 
             & " EMPNO, EMPNAME,LOGDATE,LOGINTIME " _ 
             & " FROM VWLogTransactions WHERE LOGDATE >='" & Format(dtpFrom.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' " _ 
             & " AND LOGDATE <='" & Format(dtpTo.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "'" _ 
             & " ORDER BY LOGDATE ASC, EMPNAME '
```

Comment: pls post your code ?, for better understanding

Comment: use 'YYYYMMDD' format to search date range and use >= and <= to describe your ranges rather then using between operator.

Comment: @M.Ali why not use BETWEEN? As for formatting, it's best (also easiest and fastest) to use DateTime parameters

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: [what do between and the devil have in common](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I haven't seen you code, but most often this will fix date issues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I created views 'VIEW

    SELECT EMPNO, EMPNAME,CONVERT(CHAR(10),DTDATE,103) AS LogDate, CONVERT(CHAR(10),DTDATE,108) AS  LogTime, From LogTransactions.
'

Comment: here is the vb.net script 'strSQLSelect = " SELECT " _
                     & " EMPNO, EMPNAME,LOGDATE,LOGINTIME " _
                     & " FROM VWLogTransactions WHERE LOGDATE >='" & Format(dtpFrom.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "' " _
                     & " AND LOGDATE <='" & Format(dtpTo.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "'" _
                     & " ORDER BY LOGDATE ASC, EMPNAME
'

Comment: @user3193869 Please see the link in my previous comment and start using parameterized queries. This will fix date issues and protect you against SQL injection.

Comment: Hi @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå sorry but im new in vb would you mind to assist me...please